# load image if It's valid in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just want to implement this simple thing. just using fetch API to check If It's exist or not. but It seems not working. what how can I do this?

**template**

```
img(:src='item.thumbnail' v-if('isExist(imgSrc)')
img(:src='defaultImg' v-else)
```

**JS**

```
isExist(url) {
   fetch(url, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then(() => true)
      .fail(() => false)
  }
```

Comment: Are you using a pre-compirler or transpiler for your template? BTW, there is not `fail()` method on `Promise`, use `catch()` instead.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski It occurs cross domain issue. how can I bypass it?!